# Background-Image Re-Sizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, background-image, image-resizing

After Adding A background Image there is a white space left.
when bg-size is changed to 'cover' while re sizing to small resolution there is white space left please check yourself 
[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVjzZy)

```
body {
  margin:0;
  background-image:url('http://www.fg-a.com/wallpapers/yellow-flowers-green.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:auto;
}
```

Comment: B careful some browsers has problem with css background resize like mozilla

Answer (score 0):

You've got right the `background-size:cover;` but...
you're just missing the `background-position` property.

The simplest way is like:

```
html, body{
    height:100%; /* Don't forget to set html and body to height 100%! */
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: url('green.jpg') 50%; /* where 50% is our background-position (center) */
    background-size: cover;
}
```

that's really all you need.
http://jsbin.com/bogacad/1/edit?html,css,output

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Comment: @akash have you added (like I've said) `html, body {height: 100%; }` ? No.

Comment: sorry i did add that in my editor and didn't save it thanks sir.how does the 50% works ??

Comment: @akash you're welcome! (no need to call me "sir"). Happy coding!